# Visual Studio Code: official TypeScript extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

So I have a git repository that has some .js files and some .ts files, and I just installed VSCode and opened its folder with it.

Seems like syntax highlighting works out of the box in both JavaScript and TypeScript without installing anything, great.

However, the semantic highlighting is another story: my `require()` lines at the top of the files are underlined in red, in the case of .ts files (.js files are good, not underlined), denoting the error message `[ts] cannot find name 'require'`.

So I figured it's because I need a VSCode extension, however if I search for "typescript" there are so many extensions! And it's not clear which one is the official one from Microsoft. Can anyone tell me which one is THE ONE?

Cheers

Comment: As far as I know you don't need any extra extensions for typescript to work in vscode.

Comment: `npm i -D @types/node`

Comment: then why `require(foo)` is underlined in red?

Comment: Because `require()` is a part of `nodejs`?

Comment: and why `require(foo)` is not underlined in red in .js files?

Comment: Because `js` is not as strict as `typescript` and it doesn't care (at run-time) what you are doing (as long as syntax is valid).

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** There is no "the ONE" - Typescript should work out of the box.

**More info**:
If it's not, you will need to dig deeper or provide more context in your question. I suspect something may be up with your project - have you tried creating a smaller subset of your project to see if that works?